# T-SQL color and format lost when copy many rows in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have SQL Server Management Studio version 18.5. I write a long stored procedure (350 lines). I want to copy the stored procedure to Microsoft Word. I use CTRL+C in SSMS and CTRL+V in word. The result in word is the color and font style of the code lost. But if i divided copy to 4 part (rows 1-100 then 101-200 then 201-300 then 301-350), the text in word is same color and format with SSMS.

My question is how to increase the capability of SSMS so it can maintain the color and format of the source code if i copy many rows (300 more rows)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about programming.

Comment: @Zohar do you want i ask in what forum?

Comment: I don't know where this question would be a good fit, but I don't think it does fit Stackoverflow. On the other hand, I'm the only one that voted to close - so perhaps I'm wrong about that.